# React Native problem with autolinking.gradle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I started a project with npx create-expo-app myapp --template and chose bare, and then I started with npx react-native start, but when trying to run npx react-native run-android it gives the following error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL6Y6.png)

```
PS C:\Programação\myapp> npx react-native run-android        
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Programa��o\myapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'myapp'.
> Could not read script 'C:\Programação\myapp\node_modules\expo\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Settings file 'C:\Programa��o\myapp\android\settings.gradle' line: 11 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'myapp'. > Could not 
read script 'C:\Programação\myapp\node_modules\expo\scripts\autolinking.gradle' as it does not exist. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I tried running npx react-native doctor, but it says everything is fine:

```
PS C:\Programação\myapp> npx react-native doctor     
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Metro - Required for bundling the JavaScript code

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Errors:   0
Warnings: 0
```

I'm not finding any solution on the internet. I'm thinking it could be a problem with Windows itself, as I've already tried starting different projects and deleting the android folder and creating it again but the error continues.

Has anyone experienced this and managed to resolve it?

Comment: Why not use Expo to manage your project for you?  Why use RN CLI ? The error seems to indicate a missing Expo dependency, but you are using the RN CLI...maybe try running `npx expo-doctor`?  But honestly, consider using Expo to do the build.